# ios 5 opening a specific viewcontroller with the correct TabBar and NavController wrapped

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I will try to explain this as best as I can.

My application has a TabBarController which functions as the main navigation

I have a modal view that I segue to to add a list.  that screen can be reached from 2 different viewcontrollers.

From the main route I simple just close the modal and all is fine.  However from the second route I need to be able to open up an entirely new ViewController.

The issue that I am having is that I can not seem to open that ViewController with the TabBar and NavBar included.

This is the code I am currently playing with to try to get it to work.

```
    UITabBarController *tabController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainInterface"];
    tabController.selectedIndex = 1;
    //_window.rootViewController = tabController;
    UINavigationController *groceryNavController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainNavController"];
    UIViewController *groceryViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GroceryViewController"];

    UIViewController *currentVC = self;
    [currentVC.navigationController pushViewController:groceryViewController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to to do it is through the delegate. If in the delegate, the relevant navigation controller is called:

```
self.navigationController
```

Then you would have to do:

```
YourAppDelegate *delegate = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[delegate.navigationController pushViewController:groceryViewController animated:YES];
```

(replace "YourAppDelegate" with the actual name of your app delegate)

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work.  I have used your model but the viewcontroller is not being displayed.